# generic struct types has each receiver function

Tags: go, generics, design-patterns

I'm trying to use generic struct to share the init logic between all types of struct.
But for some of logic, each type of the generic struct should have its own logic.

The error is from my Scan function for Setting[Bool] receiver. it keeps has below error when assign a typed bool to any variable. `cannot use val (variable of type bool) as bool value in assignment`

[image]
[image]

Is this because i misused the receiver ?
here is my example

```golang
type Available interface {
    int32 | string | bool
}

type Flag[T Available] interface {
    Get(ctx context.Context) (T, error)
    Set(ctx context.Context, value T) error

    Scan(persistedValue string) (T, error)
    Value() (T, error)
}

type Setting[T Available] struct {
    key          string
    defaultValue T
    value        T
}

func (setting Setting[T]) Get(ctx context.Context) (T, error) {
    settingValue, err := store.Get(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return val, Error{err}
    }

    if !settingValue.Exist {
        return setting.defaultValue, nil
    }

    setting.Scan(settingValue.Value)

    return setting.Value, nil
}

func (setting *Setting[bool]) Scan(persistedValue string) (val bool, err error) {
    val, err = strconv.ParseBool(persistedValue)
    if err != nil {
        return val, fmt.Errorf("parse %s failed: %w", setting.key, err)
    }
    return val, nil
}
```

Comment: `func (*Setting[bool]) Scan(...)` defines a generic function whose type parameter is named 'bool' by shadowing 'bool' type. The receiver is not for the `bool` instance of the generic type, it is still the same generic type whose type parameter name is `bool`.

Comment: does that mean i can't define multiple Scan function for each types ? i can only have one `func (*Setting[T]) Scan(..)` ? any suggestion how i can define the Scan func for each types ?

Comment: Correct. You cannot specialize templates like you can do in C++. You should be able to do a type-switch though

Comment: However, if you need something like this, maybe you should change your approach, because generics may not be a good fit here.